# pcre regex to match first two words, numbers

Tags: php, regex, string, pcre

I need a regular expression to match only the first two words (they may contain letters , numbers, commas and other punctuation but not white spaces, tabs or new lines) in a string.
My solution is `([^\s]+\s+){2}` but if it matches  something like :*'123 word'* *in '123 word, hello'*, it doesnt work on a string with just two words and no spaces after.

What is the right regex for this task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have it almost right:

```
(\S+\s+\S+)
```

Assuming you don't need stronger control on what characters to use.

If you need to match both two words or only one word only, you may use one of those:

```
(\S+\s+\S|\S+)
(\S+(?:\s+\S+)?)
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to match the words, you could split the string on whitespace with `preg_split()`.

Comment: +1 that's great idea, but for me without mentioning `$limit` in [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) is just terrible overkill (you may have strings really long).

Comment: ive thougth of useing preg_split but i have some reason to stick up with regex. Thank you anyway

Comment: Vyktor +1 for limit in preg_split

Answer (score 1):

If you really only want to allow numbers and letters `[^\s]` is not restrictive enough. Use this:

```
/[a-z0-9]+(\s+[a-z0-9]+)?/i
```